# selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot does not work but selenium.captureScreenshot works

Tags: selenium, screenshot, selenium-rc

I'm running Selenium with TestNG using Eclipse and Selenium RC. I used the command:

```
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("\\test.png","");
```

but got the following error:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]
```

Can someone please suggest why this error is occuring? I have already tried the following:

1)Replaced "" (String kwargs parameter) with "background=#CCFFDD"

2)Running in Firefox in chrome mode

3)Changed the path to the following values and I'm still getting the error:
"\test.jpg",
"c:\test.jpg",
"c:\test.png",
"c:\folder1\test.png", (folder1 exists)
"c:\folder1\test.jpg",

4)Tried with - selenium.captureScreenshot("\test.png"); and it works fine but it does not solve my purpose and I dont want to use awt.

Can someone please suggest what could be wrong?

Thanks,
Mugen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whomsoever it may concern,. the problem was solved after I kept fiddling with the code for a while and restarted my system. I came to know that captureEntirePageScreenshot works only on absolute paths so I made sure I kept trying with just that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot(path + "\\test.png", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Better yet...

I ran into a similar issue, where I only had access to a relative path instead of an absolute one. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
public void saveScreenshot(String methodName) {
    if (methodName == null) {
        methodName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    File f = new File("reports" + File.separator + methodName + ".jpg");
    selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot(f.getAbsolutePath(), "");
}
```

Which will put a screen shot of the entire page into the `reports` directory that is relative to the project. I am using the method name as the file name, or the current time if null is sent to the method.

Answer (score -1):

I got it working after looking at this page.

http://ashishbhatt.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/using-captureentirepagescreenshot-with-selenium/

Comment: don't post just a link otherwise your answer is worthless if the link breaks